# How can one have axis-view?

Tags: 3d-view

I can't find a single guide/tutorial or any reply to help me out on this one.

So how to reset your view so that you can see the selected and focused object from "axis view" so that you can inspect it from x,y,z axis, and i'm not looking for close enough view. But 100% axis view.(for example behind you is x- and infront of you is x) (focused by numbad ","). So you can see it in "2D", meaning if it's a 3D square (with no self-rotation) you can be able to see only 1 side of it.

Comment: Not sure, but it sounds like you're describing Orthographic view. Press NumPad 5 to toggle between Orthographic and Perspective views.

Comment: Since you are starting with blender, please use the links on this page to find basic information:  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender

Answer (score 6):

### Z axis:

<kbd>Numberpad 7</kbd> for Top View

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numberpad 7</kbd>for Bottom View

### X axis:

<kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> for Right View.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> for Left View.

### Y axis:

<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>  for Front View

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> for Back View

### Toggles

<kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> toggles between **Orthographic** and **Perspective** view.

For best results, go into File -> User Preferences..., "Interface" tab, and make sure there is a checkmark on on `Auto Perspective`.  If that isn't set, you may end up with a perspective (instead of orthographic) view along the selected axis.
If your view isn't centered on the selected object, press the <kbd>Numpad .</kbd> (period) key.

More information on the manual page: [Editors » 3D Viewport » Navigating » Navigation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/editors/3dview/navigate/navigation.html)

### Axis Gizmo

In Blender 2.80 and higher, an axis gizmo can be clicked to get Orthographic views:

[image: Blender 2.80 Axis Gizmo]

Answer (score 5):

Also useful is the control key for the above views:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> (bottom view)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> (back view)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> (left view)